# Create an object using a custom function's passed parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, object

I tried searching for this but really couldn't find just a super simple answer for this.

I want to be able to create an object with a name that is given by a parameter.

I.e. something like this:

```
var createThing = function (param) {
    var param = new Object();
}
```

I don't want an object called `param` rather an object with that is named after the string that is passed in as the parameter. I.e. if someone calls:

```
createThing(inventoryA);
```

I want to be able to have an object created called `inventoryA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try :

```
var createThing = function (param) {
    return window[param] = new Object();
}
createThing('inventoryA');
console.log(inventoryA);
```

this will create a object in the window scope with the name you given.

with **nodejs** you can use:

```
var createThing = function (param) {
    return global[param] = new Object();
}
```

Comment: would there be a way to do this in node.js as opposed to running in the browser?

Comment: It should be noted that doing this is a bad idea especially because it can introduce hard to debug issues...

Comment: @mscdex , what would be the best practice alternative to this? And what would be a good example of a hard to debug issue.